# NSString to NSDate conversion with GMT value

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to set the date formatter setformat option for a date string like this to get NSDate object??

```
31-07-2012 11:00:00 GMT 05:30
```

I just need the formatter string to work out on this function OR is there something more to do to get date from this string??

-(void)setDateFormat:(NSString *)string;

Note: I know and worked on the NSDateformatter but cant sort this one out....!!!

Comment: Are you going to parsing date from this string?

Comment: No idea why someone downvote you.

Comment: It should be mandatory to comment why he/she does, when downvoting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this blog describes the NSDate and NSString very clear. http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-1/. You can refer it.

Comment: I found a formatter that works for only "31-07-2012 11:00:00 GMT+05:30". But if there is on "+" between GMT and the timezone, the pattern doesn't work. Here it is "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ". If I get any further, I'll post it.

Comment: yup ...i found tht working with + sign..but hav to make sure there is no method to implement it other way ..so asked..Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

if the format is

```
31-07-2012 11:00:00 GMT+05:30
```

you can use

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ssZZZZ"]
```